# Select the last price according to the date using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to do a request with a group BY.

Here is an exemple of my table ticket :

```
id       DtSell       Price       Qt
1        01-01-2017   3.00        1
1        02-01-2017   2.00        3
2        01-01-2017   5.00        5
2        02-01-2017   8.00        2
```

And my request :

```
SELECT id, Price, sum(Qt) FROM ticket
GROUP BY id;
```

but unfortunately, the price returned is not necessarily the right one; I would like to have the last price according to DtSell like that :

```
id       Price       sum(Qt)
1        2.00        4
2        8.00        7
```

But i didn't find how to do it.
Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
SELECT id, Price, SUM(Qt)
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY dtsell DESC), ',' 1) as last_price
FROM ticket
GROUP BY id;
```

Two notes:

- This is subject to internal limits on the length of the intermediate string used for `GROUP_CONAT()` (a limit that can easily be changed).
- It changes the type of `price` to a string.

Answer (score 3):

You might need a sub query,try below:

```
   SELECT 
    t1.id,
    (SELECT t2.price FROM ticket t2 WHERE t2.id=t1.id 
       ORDER BY t2.DtSell DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS price, 
    SUM(t1.Qt) 
     FROM ticket t1 GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Comment: it seems to be the simplest solution, i'll use that thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT id, Price, sum(Qt) FROM ticket
GROUP BY id,Price
```

Your Output;

```
id       Price       sum(Qt)
1        3.00        4
2        8.00        7
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I had already thought about that but unfornately the result is not the right one, I have all the prices displayed for each id..

Answer (score 0):

You can select all rows from ticket grouped by id ( to sum quantity), then join to the rows which have the max dtsell for each id group( to select the price).
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/574cb9/8

```
SELECT t.id
         , t3.price
         , SUM(t.Qt)
    FROM   ticket t
    JOIN   ( SELECT t1.id
                  , t1.price
             FROM   ticket t1
             JOIN   ( SELECT id
                           , MAX(dtsell) dtsell
                      FROM   ticket
                      GROUP  BY id ) t2
               ON t1.id      = t2.id
              AND t1.dtsell = t2.dtsell ) t3
      ON t3.id = t.id
    GROUP  BY t.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
declare @t table (id int, dtsell date, price numeric(18,2),qt int)

insert into @t

values

(1        ,'01-01-2017',   3.00     ,  1),
(1        ,'02-01-2017',   2.00     ,  3),
(2        ,'01-01-2017',   5.00     ,  5),
(2        ,'02-01-2017',   8.00     ,  2)

select x.id,price,z.Qt from (
select id,price,dtsell,row_number() over(partition by id order by dtsell desc ) as rn from @t
)x 
inner join (select SUM(qt) as Qt,ID from @t group by id ) z on x.id = z.id
where rn = 1
```